# Reading multiple files into separate data frames in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I want to know if there's a way in python for reading multiple CSV file form a folder and assigning to separate data frame by the name of the file. The below code will throw an error but to show the point I pasted it

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    index = filename.find(".csv")
    if "test" in filename:
        filename[:index]) = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need create `dictionary of DataFrame` with `keys` by filenames:

```
d = {}
for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    if "test" in filename:
        d[filename[:-4]] = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

What is same as:

```
d = {f[:-4]: pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('*.csv') if "test" in f}
```

If want only name of file is possible use:

```
d = {os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0]:pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('*.csv') if "test" in f}
```